# Download Files using a For Each Loop

Tags: file, for-loop, download, each, loader

Please keep in mind that I am a TOTAL NOOB.  I am not asking anyone to code my entire project, but I am easily lost in many cases.  Your help and patience is much appreciated ...

My AS3 code looks something like this:

```
var totalFeatureImageDownloads:Number = 0;  //total file size of all feature images, in bytes
var totalFeatureImageDownloaded:Number = 0; //total downloaded of all feature images, in bytes

for each(var featureimage:XML in xml.featureimages.imgurl)
  {
  trace(featureimage);
  var featureImageRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(featureimage);
  var featureImageLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(featureImageRequest);
  totalFeatureImageDownloads = totalFeatureImageDownloads + featureImageLoader.bytesTotal;
  trace(featureImageLoader.bytesTotal);
  }
```

Currently I have 3 images in the XML file, and their URL's are traced properly.  However, bytesTotal always equals 0.  Also, I know that this loop creates 3 identically named URLRequest's and 3 identically named URLLoaders.  I probably need to create 3 differently named ones.

I would like all the images to be downloaded simultaneously, and I need to calculate the combined file size for all three, along with the download status as a fraction (bytesLoaded / bytesTotal).

I have multiple scenarios like this, and am stuck until I get this finished.  Your help is much appreciated.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read the bytesTotal from a newly created URLLoader, because the client needs to connect to the web server first to get the size of the file to be downloaded. You need to listen for the first `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` event sent by the URLLoader, once that event is sent the bytesTotal property is more likely to be accurate. I say "more likely" because it is not possible to get a total file size if the data is dynamically generated on the server, but in the general case where you download a file from the server it works.

I recognize the general scenario. There are libraries to aid with this, such as LoaderMax or BulkLoader. I personally use BulkLoader: https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader